# Is it possible to install more than one os in one pen drive?

Tags: operating-systems, usb-storage

Hello I have a one confusion question that is it possible that make bootable pendrive but not with one os but more than one os.

Like..
When pendrive load.. show me the option of which one install?

```
Windows Vista
Windows 7
Windows 8
```

So is it possible?

Kindly reply me..

Regards..

Thanks..

Comment: I think it's possible with GRUB or something similar, but it won't be so nice to configure.

Comment: @matan129..why??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a multiboot CD that will start a user-chosen ISO file](http://superuser.com/questions/267385/how-to-make-a-multiboot-cd-that-will-start-a-user-chosen-iso-file)

Comment: @EightBitTony.. you can just read it.. its not for flash drive so remove the upper heading.. i want in flash drive

Comment: You might want to change your title to reflect making access to multiple OS installers, as opposed to actually installing multiple OS's.

Comment: @JavaD: "you can just read it.. its not for flash drive so remove the upper heading" - Did *you* bother reading all the answers there? YUMI's site mentions support for the Windows XP/Vista/7/8 installers, and Sardu's site has a page named **Windows** that clearly states how you can **Install all Windows from the some USB or DVD**. When people point you to an existing resource it's expected that you do some research instead of simply dismissing their effort. *If* none of the solutions help then you can post a query about it, but till then I agree with EightBitTony that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right solution for me :)

[Super disk multi boot](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/94398-super-disc-multi-boot-project-cddvd-using-isolinux/)